# Probability of two uniform random variables

Tags: probability

x and y are uniformly distributed over the interval [0,1]. Find the probability that  |x-y|, the distance between x and y, is less than 0.35.

I tried to graph the function with x being on the x axis, and y being on the y axis. So I would get a square with uniform density and area 1. Then I tried to graph the function |x-y|<.35 and then integrate over that area. I couldn't seem to get the right answer. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Your general plan looks sound. If you want to know what went wrong in executing it, you'll need to show more of the calculations that gave the wrong result.

Comment: am i just taking the area in quadrant 1? or do i count the area of all 4 quadrants with area 1 to account for the absolute value sign?

Comment: Just quadrant 1, indeed just in the square wuth corners $(0,0)$, $1,0$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$ since that's where the joint density lives. draw the line $y-x=0.35$ and $y=-0.35$. we want the area ofthe part of the square between these lines. It is a little easier to find the combined area of the two parts od the square not between the two lines. These are simple triangles,

Comment: Just the area within the unit square. The absolute sign means: $$\lvert x-y\rvert < 0.35 \iff -0.35 < x-y < 0.35$$

Answer (score 1):

The constrained area is the portion of the unit square between the lines $y=x-0.35$ and $y=x+0.35$ . That's the $\Bbb R^2$ interval:
 $$\langle x, y\rangle \in [0;1]\times [\max\{0, x-0.35\};\min\{1,x+0.35\}]$$

This can be subdivided into $\langle x,y\rangle\in \left(\substack{\begin{align}\large [0;0.35)&\large\times[0;x+0.35)
\\ \large\cup[0.35;0.65)&\large\times[x-0.35;x+0.35)
\\\large \cup[0.65;1]&\large\times[x-0.35;1]\end{align}}\right)$

Thus the integral is $$\mathsf P(A) = \int_0^{0.35}\int_0^{x+0.35} \operatorname d y\operatorname d x + \int_{0.35}^{0.65}\int_{x-0.35}^{x+0.35} \operatorname d y\operatorname d x+\int_{0.65}^1\int_{x-0.35}^{1}\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$

---

However, its a little easier to evaluate as 1 minus the complement's probability.

$$\mathsf P(A) = 1 - \int_{0}^{0.65}\int_{x+0.35}^{1}\operatorname dy\operatorname dx - \int_{0.35}^1\int_{0}^{x-0.35}\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$

Which is the unit square minus two triangles of side $0.65$.  Why even integrate when you can just use the area of a triangle: $\tfrac 12 BH$?